# is it possible to provide variable arguments to xinetd service?

Tags: linux, networking, bash, scripting, xinetd

I have created a bash script to listen on specific port (using xinetd), so whenever there is someone connecting to port, then it invokes the script and provides its output to user. But i need to provide dynamic arguments to server, for example when i telnet to server like

```
telnet myserver 4535
```

then i should be able to pass an argument like my name "Frank" and it should say

```
"Hello Frank"
```

There is a parameter of server-args in xinetd config, but i am not sure that arguments to it can be passed dynamically through the telnet or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the initial telnet command line, I doubt you'll be able to put passable arguments.  However, as part of the transactions between the server and client you'll certainly be able to do something like this.